# Return Column Based on Another Specific Value

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm trying to show which products our company offers have been purchased by a certain point in time. I would like to show each product's name and then a simple Y or N next to each product indicating if it was sold by a certain date. I'm not sure how to structure the query - this is my attempt

```
SELECT product_offering as Product
CASE WHEN date_key='2017-03-30' THEN product_sold ELSE product_sold END as Sold
FROM table1
```

It should look like, if, as a shortened example

1st product sold 2017-03-27

2nd product sold 2017-04-03

3rd product sold 2017-3-28

```
|Product | Sold |
|1st Prod|   Y  |
|2nd Prod|   N  |
|3rd Prod|   Y  |
```

Instead, the "Sold" column isn't entirely accurate. I think this has something to do with the date being equal to a certain date instead of a range leading up to, but i'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Edit your question and show sample data or the data layout.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want something like this:

```
SELECT product_offering as Product,
       (CASE WHEN MIN(date_key) <= '2017-03-30' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) as Sold
FROM table1
GROUP BY table1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query to achieve this:

```
Select product,(case when min(date_key)<='2017-03-
30' then 'y' else 'n' end) as sold from table1 group by product
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem correctly i.e. You need to compare column `date_key` to a `date value` (which in your example is `2017-03-30`)  and if its less, then return `Y` else `N`. In that case, i don't think aggregation is needed.

You just need `case`.

```
select product_offering as Product,
       case when date_key <= DATE '2017-03-30' then 'Y' else 'N' end as Sold
from table1
order by product_offering
```

`<=` or `<` in above query depending whether you want to include `date value` or not.

**Result:**

```
+-------------+------+
|   PRODUCT   | SOLD |
+-------------+------+
| 1st product | Y    |
| 2nd product | N    |
| 3rd product | Y    |
+-------------+------+
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/23c4d8/6)**

*P.S. Above demo is also valid for `teradata` (and has already been tested)*